# Error Database Triggered Cloud function with Promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a firebase cloud function that essentially does 2 things for now:

1) gets triggered whenever a user comes online/offline

2) fetch all the conversations for this user.

The below code is able to perform Step 1, but returns Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value Error in the console.

I am not sure how to write Promises and this is my first Firebase function. Please assist.

```
    exports.offlineHandler = functions.database.ref('/users/{userid}/status')
      .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const status = change.after.val();
        const userId = context.params.userid;
        console.log('the user is now ', status, "with mobile no ", userId);
        // fetch a users conversations list
        if (status === "offline") {
          console.log("offline exec start");
          return fetchUserConversations(userId)
            .then(results => {
              console.log("offline exec end");
              for (result in results) {
                console.log("id is", result);
              }
              return results;
            }).catch(err => {
              console.error("An error has occurred.", err);
              return err;
            });
        } else {
          console.log("user came online");
        }
        return null;
      });

function fetchUserConversations(userId) {
  return admin.firestore().collection('users/${userId}/conversations').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      var conversations = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("This is conversation id => ", doc.id);
        conversations.concat(doc.id);
      });
      return conversations;
      //return conversations;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return err;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, you seem to be just be missing a `return` before `fetchUserConversations(userId)...`. So:

```
return fetchUserConversations(userId).then(result=>{
```

To learn more about promises in Cloud Functions, you'd do best to study the Firebase documentation on [sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), and Doug Stevenson's excellent video series on [using promises in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&feature=emb_logo).

---

A more fundamental problem with your code is that it doesn't do anything with the conversations it fetches for the user. It seems that you're trying to return them from the Cloud Function, but Cloud Functions that are triggered by a database write cannot return anything. Such Functions are triggered by a database write, **not** by a user operation.

While in your case it was a user operation (coming back online) that triggered the Cloud Function, that's an indirect trigger and you can't return anything to the user from the Cloud Function.

You have two main options here:

1. Write the conversations somewhere in the database that the user then looks them up.
2. Change the Cloud Functions trigger type to be HTTPS or Callable, and then call this Cloud Function from your application code when the user goes back online.

Comment: yes that is the next step. I need to write all the offline/ remove all the online users to/from an offline register inside firestore of these individual conversations. but not able to return the conversations[] itself.

Comment: after adding a return to the fetchUserConversations() get the following error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at exports.offlineHandler.functions.database.ref.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:15:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: updated to the latest changes as suggested. Please assist @Frank

Comment: You're also missing a `return` here: `return admin.firestore().collection('users/${userId}/conversations').get()`. I really recommend spending some more time getting to grips with promises in Cloud Functions based on the links I gave in my answer, as once you grok promises it's a matter of following the trail left by the error message.

Comment: Hi Frank already did go through those but could and understand the concept in principle but it still refuses to work completely. So, still even with the return statement cannot get the resultant logs inside the call to collection().get() . Please see if you could help out while I also try to figure it out.

Comment: I expect the error message to change once you made the change I proposed.